# Copying large MySQL table in background

Tags: mysql

I need to copy a large (80 mil records) MySQL table into another table as I need to add an index to the table and using ALTER would just be too slow / run out of RAM.

I've tried running a MySQL script containing INSERT INTO table2 SELECT * FROM table1 in a screen instance so that I can detach and exit the SSH session, but for some reason it did the first 20 million rows (which took a couple of hours) and then it randomly stopped. Would this method require a lot of memory? How else can I do this fast and in the background?

Comment: Are you inserting into a table where the index(es) are already defined?

Comment: you must insert with a loop and commit every 1000 records by example. In a "PROCEDURE".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dump the table into a .csv file

```
mysqldump -u [username] -p -t -T/path/to/directory/file.txt [database] [table]  --fields-terminated-by=,
```

Create a new table with the proper schema

Then load the new table with the .csv data in it

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/directory/file.txt' INTO TABLE database.new_table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
```

FYI: these commands aren't tested and may need some adjusting, but you should get the idea

Comment: Thanks, I used this in conjunction with a SELECT to export only the columns I wanted.